# Match specific length words, anchored, without doing magic math

Tags: regex, grep

Let's say I wanted to find all 12-letter words in `/usr/share/dict/words` that started with `c` and ended with `er`. Off the top of my head, a workable pattern could look something like:

```
grep -E '^c.{9}er$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

It finds:

```
cabinetmaker
calcographer
calligrapher
campanologer
campylometer
...
```

But that `.{9}` bothers me. It feels too *magical*, subtracting the total length of all the anchor characters from the number defined in the original constraint.

Is there any way to rewrite this regex so it doesn't require doing this calculation up front, allowing a literal `12` to be used directly in the pattern?

Comment: what is included in letter? Try `\bc[a-zA-Z]{9}er\b`. Dot matches any character other than `\n` new line.

Comment: It still has a `9` in it; that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Here is a caveman regex: `grep -E ^c.........er$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-x` option which selects only matches that exactly match the whole line.

```
grep -xE '.{12}' | grep 'c.*er'
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/GLKz2p)

Or use the `-P` option which clarifies the pattern as a Perl regular expression and use a lookahead assertion.

```
grep -P '^(?=.{12}$)c.*er$'
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/cWyZGo)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` as an alternative and avoid this calculation:

```
awk -v len=12 'length($1)==len && $1 ~ /^c.*?er$/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `grep` so well, but some more advanced NFA RegEx implementations provide you with lookaheads and lookbehinds. If you can figure out any means to make those available for you, you could write:

`^(?=c).{12}(?<=er)$`

Maybe as a `perl` one-liner like this?

`cat /usr/share/dict/words | perl -ne "print if m/^(?=c).{12}(?<=er)$/"`

Comment: To use perl regular expresion with GNU grep you need the `-P` option.

Answer (score 0):

One approach with `GNU sed`:

```
$ sed -nr '/^.{12}$/{/^c.*er$/p}' words
```

With `BSD sed` *(Mac OS)* it would be:

```
$ sed -nE '/^.{12}$/{/^c.*er$/p;}' words
```